# Simulate the appearance of a plane illuminated by a nearby point source

Tags: graphics3d, lighting

I'd like to simulate the appearance of a diffusely reflecting plane surface illuminated by a nearby point source.

```
Graphics3D[{Lighting -> {{"Point", White, {0, 0, 1}}},
  FaceForm[White], 
  Polygon[
     {{-10, -10, 0}, 
      {-10, 10, 0}, 
      {10, 10, 0}, 
      {10, -10, 0}, 
      {-10, -10, 0}}]},
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {0, 10}},
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image: plane illuminated by point source]

Notice that the sole point source is at {0,0,1}, just above the surface at its center.  What *should* appear is that the *center* of the plane should appear bright (because it is near the source just above the center, and for geometric reasons) while the edges (distant portions) of the plane should appear dark.  That doesn't happen.

I've adjusted properties of the specularity and such, never able to get the expected bright region in the center.

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't need the `Specularity[]` part, since this will add a glossy surface lighting (probably Phong or something similar) which creates the brightest highlight on the plane where you could see the light source (if it had an extent) mirrored instead of where the distance is closest to the surface as with diffuse lighting. I couldn't get it working with only diffuse lighting, but i think that's more at the heart of the issue.

Comment: OK... so I'll resimulate with the specularity eliminated and re-post.  Thanks.

Comment: The documentation says that light from point sources does not attenuate with distance (without using the fourth list element). Without attenuation, I don't think you would expect to see the bright spot in the middle. If you were to place other objects blocking the light, then those would cast shadows, showing that there is a point source just as there should be. I don't have much time right now, my initial attempt with attenuation did not succeed, however. Also, the figure you posted no longer matches the code.

Comment: Ah... yes... attenuation.  Thanks.  I will try that tomorrow.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to @C.E., who set me on the right path:

```
plane = DiscretizeRegion[
  InfinitePlane[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}], 
  {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.01}, 
  BaseStyle -> {EdgeForm[], White}]; 
 Show[plane,
 Lighting -> {{"Point", White, {0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 1}}}]
```

[image]

There's more code and coloring, but this is the ultimate figure I needed:

[image]

I realize why trying to render a single plane will not work:  *Mathematica*'s routines render the *entire* plane with a single `FaceForm[]`, so you must break a plane into small areas, each of which can be rendered a different color/brightness.  This is also why rendering a sphere is unproblematic—it consists of lots of small planes.

Comment: You can add the `Lighting->...` option to `BaseStyle` in `DiscretizeRegion`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the viewpoint direction has a lot to do with it.  Here is an example, similar to yours that emphasizes the point:

```
n = 6; th = (2 \[Pi])/n Range[n + 1];
p = Polygon[Transpose[{Cos[th], Sin[th], ConstantArray[0, n + 1]}]];
g = Graphics3D[{Specularity[White, 10], Lighting -> {{"Point", White, {0, 0, 2}}}, 
      FaceForm[Blue], p}]
```

Now, rotate the viewpoint so that you are looking directly down towards the center of the hexagon,

```
Show[%, Viewpoint -> {0, -\[Infinity], 0}]
```

(I am a bit surprised that the y-coordinate is non-zero, not the z-coordinate)

and then perturb it a little ...

Comment: This answer was in response to the original posting, with specularity.

Comment: Yes... but even with everything adjusted, your code apparently cannot yield the bright center region we know must occur.  Thanks, though.

Comment: Changing `Lighting -> {{"Point", White, {0, 0, 2}}` to `Lighting -> {{"Point", White, {0, 0, 20}}` turns it up pretty bright.

Comment: But placing the source point *far* from the surface is precisely what we *shouldn't* do.  Even if it makes the overall image bright, it fails to give a large *difference* in brightness between the center and the edge.

Comment: I think another aspect of this, is the shape of the polygon.  With flat surfaces, it is hard to get that "bright spot".  The example in the documentation with four spheres gives a nice "spotlight" on each of the spheres because of the curvature.

Comment: Hold a candle near your carpeted (Lambertian) floor in an otherwise dark room.  *THAT* is what I'm trying to simulate.  The sphere specularity is particularly effective when there is specular ("mirror-like") reflection from the surface—precisely what I want to avoid.  And I certainly don't want to use a cylindrical or other baffle, which thwarts the physical phenomenon in question.

Comment: Instead of a point source, you may want to put a light source within a cylinder, sort of like a recessed light.

Comment: Perhaps you want a Lambertian reflectance?