# True neutral lighting in ParametricPlot3D

Tags: graphics3d, lighting

I would like to generate a sphere with uniform surface brightness:

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 {Cos[θ] Sin[φ], Sin[θ] Sin[φ], Cos[φ]},
 {θ, 0, 2 π},
 {φ, 0, π},
 PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}},
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, GrayLevel[.5]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

but this leads to a sphere is darker shading at the bottom:

[image: shaded sphere]

I've tried all manner of `Lighting -> None`, `"None"`, etc., but still get either everything black or with the shading shown.

How do I get truly neutral ambient lighting, so the only variation in the appearance of the sphere is given by my `ColorFunction`?

`Lighting-> {"Ambient"->White}` simply does not work:

[image]

(version 11.3)

Comment: ``Lighting -> {"Ambient", White}``

Comment: ...and if your colors aren't parameter-dependent, just use `PlotStyle`; thus: `Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, PlotStyle -> GrayLevel[.5], PlotTheme -> None`

Comment: Why not use the point light source from a previous question, and place it at the center of the sphere?

Comment: What version are you using? ``Lighting -> {"Ambient", White}`` works beautifully for me on macOS 11.3

Comment: Yes, `Lighting -> {"Ambient", White}` also works on a Mac with *Mathematica* 11.2.

Comment: The lighting you complain about is perfectly neutral; it just happens to be directional. That's why you need to add `"Ambient"`(same in every direction) to the lighting specification.

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive:  Somehow your comment solution didn't work because it used two-levels of depth in the Lighting specification {{}}.  With one it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to show what `{"Ambient", White}` gives on macOS v11.3:

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 {Cos[θ] Sin[φ], Sin[θ] Sin[φ], 
  Cos[φ]}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, {φ, 0, π}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, GrayLevel[.5]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Lighting -> {"Ambient", White}
 ]
```

[image]

And here's the same from the Cloud:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
 ParametricPlot3D[
 {Cos[θ] Sin[φ], Sin[θ] Sin[φ], Cos[φ]},
 {θ, 0, 2 π},
 {φ, 0, π},
 PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}},
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, GrayLevel[.75]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    Lighting -> {"Point", White, {0, 0, 0}}]
```

[image]

[Lighting with a point source was discussed here, in a previous question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193463/simulate-the-appearance-of-a-plane-illuminated-by-a-nearby-point-source/193472#193472)

Answer (score 1):

Do not change the lighting. Change the surface properties instead. The key is [`Glow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Glow.html).

```
PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Glow[Red]]
```

[image]

We set the colour to black so no light is reflected (and the lighting has no effect on the rendered colour). Now whatever colour you put in `Glow[...]` will be used for rendering the entire object.

This is not only a simpler solution, it also allows mixing shaded and flat objects in the same scene.